# yql list of supported Open Data Tables

Tags: bit.ly, yql

I know there are certain apps that support Yahoo's YQL open data tables

- Twitter
- Bitly
- Flickr
- Digg

etc.

Is there a comprehensive list anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a list of some of the user contributed open data tables on github.

http://github.com/spullara/yql-tables/tree/master

Also if you go to the Console (http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/) you can run
"show tables" and it lists the tables you have access to.

Comment: very useful link that I know will come in handy for me someday.

Answer (score 3):

FYI: We moved the repo to http://github.com/yql/yql-tables